# using max to select the previous record in same table sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Iam having an issue when I want to write a query that select the previous record in a table in sql oracle.

I used max with having to make query :

```
select cur.wage ,max(prev.wage)
from t_wage prev 
inner join 
T_wage cur 
on 
cur.cntid=prev.cntid
where cur.wage=2*prev.wage
group by prev.wage
having max (prev.wage)< cur.wage
```

suppose that my table is 
[image]

I want the result to retrieve last record and compare it with the second last and if it is doubled.

I don't know how to bring the previous record regardless of the date. Can any one tell me where I got wrong?

The result should be:

```
3000   6000
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. I'd do `group by cur.wage` instead.

Comment: Your cur.wage/prev.wage conditions are all messed up. Show us the expected result as well, and I'll hopefully understand what you're trying to do. BTW, most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I want to retrieve the last and second last wage for each cntid in the table ,

Comment: who have doubled wage in previous record

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select t.
from (select t.*,
             lag(wage) over (partition by cntid order by dateid) as prev_wage
      from t
     ) t
where wage = 2 *  prev_wage;
```

Comment: I dont think that lag will work in my case bcs it basically makes the first row be the second

Comment: and I want to select the last row and the second last row  if it is doubled the last

Comment: @Mlak . . . This gives you the two values in the same row, which appears to be what your question is asking for.